# How to rename all on WinForm application for obfuscating

Tags: c#, winforms, obfuscation, deobfuscation, confuserex

I started obfuscating my application and have found great free tool called [Confuser](https://confuser.codeplex.com/), but it doesn't rename all.
I tried confuse and then deobfuscate using [de4dot](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot) and I can see many of the names.

How can I automatically rename all the namespaces, classes, properties and variables on my WinForms project?

**Update:**

- All the public classes was not renamed and the internal and private
  classes changed fully (Apart Resources internal class name)
- Just the private variables, properties and methods was renamed (Apart the controls that a form contains)

**Bottom line:**
Any public didn't change unless was on some private or internal method or class and all the controls were contained in form not changed even if was private.

Comment: Have you looked at Dotfuscator? Also, if you are protecting your app against tampering read [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt845626)

Comment: "I can see many of the names". What are they? Analyze the pattern and you should easily see what you can never rip out (as everybody can guess).

Comment: @LexLi Please see the update I wrote right now.

Comment: @crowcoder I actually doesn't see any change after Dotfuscator rename.

Comment: @Gadjid learn the configuration system. By default it is perfectly normal to keep public things untouched.

Comment: My intention of renaming is not to actually use Obfuscator. The intention is ultimately rename even if before compiling, The main thing is to operate automatically because doing it manually is not effective particularly if I want to release a new version.